# Finding the appropriate ROM - translating ROM names to something legible

Tags: rom

The Shipped ROMs site has a bunch of ROMs listed, but I can never make out which one is the one I am looking for. Using the baseband version is straightforward, but even then there are often a couple ROMs that fit.

Please excuse me if I should not be doing this, but I'll give you a concrete example:
In my case, I am looking for the stock ROM for the unlocked HTC Desire I bought in The Netherlands (I'm Belgian myself, but this makes little difference). So I looked at the Bravo page:
http://www.shipped-roms.com/index.php?category=android&model=Bravo

The baseband version is 32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27 so that gives me a list of 8 ROMs

```
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.2_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_151783_signed.exe   Binary File    
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_TELUS_WWE_2.25.661.2_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_151557_signed.exe     Binary File    
PB99IMG_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.2_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_151783_signed.zip   Archived File  
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_Vodafone_UK_2.33.161.2_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_157522_signed.exe   Binary File    
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_ARA_2.32.415.3_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_157343_signed.exe   Binary File    
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC__ARA_2.32.415.3_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_157343_signed.exe  Binary File    
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.5_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_159811_signed.exe   Binary File    
PB99IMG_2.29.405.5_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_159811_signed.zip   Archived File
```

In this list, there are a couple abbreviations I do not know or understand, such as:
WWE, ARA, RUU.

Any help, general or specific to my case, is much appreciated.
I believe I know I will need a bin and not an exe file, and I can probably rule out Telus and Vodafone ones.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that:

- "WWE" stands for "World Wide English"
- "RUU" is "Rom Update Utility"
- "ARA" means "Arabic" (which [apparently](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=853178) is for "middle eastern devices")

  <strike>"ARA" may mean "Aramean" and since it is in the same spot that "WWE" is I would guess that it refers to the localization or language like "WWE" does, so "Aramean" makes sense to me.</strike>

As you can see the RUU is an executable. You will run on your computer while your device is connected through USB.  The zip is usually installed via a recovery - however that is my experience with my HTC EVO and Hero.

Comment: also; it's possible to get zip from executable RUU. Start up RUU; and zip will be created in temp directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want .zip files, there's only 2 choices.  2.29.405.5 is newer than 2.29.405.2, so that's the one you should get.